# How do I implement similar observe event functionality for the child rows in the data table?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, dt

My code works great currently for showing a plot based off of a click in any of the parent rows.. but I'm not sure how to implement the same functionality for the child rows. I'm newer to shiny & R development so any help is appreciated!

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")
library("janitor")
library("scales")
library("DT")



##~~ Multiple levels of nesting ~~##

## data
df1 <- data.frame(
  RowName = c("A", "B", "C"),
  `chicken` = c(10, 20, 30),
  `meat` = c(15, 25, 35),
  `tea` = c(12, 22, 32),
  `food` = c(37, 67, 97),
  `plants` = c(15, 25, 35),
  `materials` = c(12, 22, 32)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  RowName = c("A", "B", "C"),
  `chicken` = c(10, 20, 30),
  `meat` = c(15, 25, 35),
  `tea` = c(12, 22, 32),
  `food` = c(37, 67, 97),
  `plants` = c(15, 25, 35),
  `materials` = c(12, 22, 32)
)

# function to make the required dataframe
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# make the required dataframe
# one must have: length(children) == nrow(dat)
# EDIT: need to use replicate() on df2 for cases when there is an arbitrary
# number of rows in df1 
n <-  nrow(df1)
children_list <- replicate(n, df2, simplify = FALSE)
Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = df1, 
  children = children_list
)

## whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
rowNames <- FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback = JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [", 
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId);",
  "  }",
  "});")



ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("myTable"),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Initial table rendering
  output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    testtable <- datatable(
      Dat, callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  # Define a reactiveValues object to store the values for the parent and child rows
  reactive_data <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
  
  observe({
    clickedIndex <- input$myTable_cell_clicked
    
    # Check if clickedIndex is not NULL and has the necessary properties
    if (!is.null(clickedIndex) && !is.null(clickedIndex$row) && !is.null(clickedIndex$col)) {
      
      clickedRow <- clickedIndex$row
      clickedColName <- colnames(Dat)[clickedIndex$col + 1 ] 
      
      # Check if the clicked column is 'food'
      if (!is.na(clickedColName) && clickedColName == "food") {
        
        # Retrieve the values for the clicked row from the desired columns and store in reactive_values
        reactive_data$values <- unlist(Dat[clickedRow, c("chicken", "meat", "tea")])
        
      } else {
        reactive_data$values <- NULL
      }
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    req(reactive_data$values) # Ensure values are present before plotting
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      x = names(reactive_data$values),
      y = as.numeric(reactive_data$values),
      type = 'bar',
      name = "Values"
    )
    fig
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I haven't been able to get this to work successfully, the graph after clicking on a child row is always blank. I don't know much javascript so any help there is also appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html) could help.